# How to open asp:HyperLink.NavigationUrl in a new tab

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

Is there a way to open an asp:HyperLink.NavigateUrl in a new tab and not change location of the current?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

use `<asp:HyperLink Target="_blank" />` actually depending on the users settings that may open a new window.

This works for a new tab in FF and Chrome, doesn't seem to work in IE (8), but this may depend on the doctype.

Comment: This also works in gridview. Example  <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="link" HeaderText="Link" DataNavigateUrlFormatString=""
                                                    DataTextField="link"  ItemStyle-Width="10%" Target="_blank"   />

Answer (score 12):

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" 
     runat="server" 
     NavigateUrl="http://yoursite.com" 
     Target="_blank">
       This will work.
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkCompUrl" runat="server"  Width="200px"></asp:HyperLink></li>


lnkCompUrl.Text = Convert.ToString(dsData.Tables[0].Rows[0]["comp_url"]);
string url="http://"+Convert.ToString(dsData.Tables[0].Rows[0]["comp_url"]);

lnkCompUrl.NavigateUrl = String.Format("javascript:void(window.open('"+url+"','_blank'));");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void grdvEmployeeDetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)

{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var firstCell = e.Row.Cells[0];            
        firstCell.Controls.Clear();           
        firstCell.Controls.Add(new HyperLink { NavigateUrl = String.Format("javascript:void(window.open('" + "EmployeeDetails.aspx?EmpId=" + firstCell.Text + "','_blank'));"), Text = firstCell.Text });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

```
[asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="..." Target="_blank" Text=".......".../]
```