# Open html page in new tab using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to open new html page in new tab using of c# inside of asp.net. I have

```
protected void btnShowMatrix_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = @"http://localhost/IMApp/static/knit.html";
        Response.Redirect(url);
    }
```

This works fine but I need to open that html page in new tab. Is there any simple way, how to do that. Many thank in advance.

Comment: Use `HyperLink`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191747/how-to-open-asphyperlink-navigationurl-in-a-new-tab

Comment: <asp:HyperLink ID="hplShowMatrix" 
                 runat="server" 
                 NavigateUrl="http://localhost/IMApp/static/knit.html" 
                 Target="_blank">Call Matrix
            </asp:HyperLink>

Works fine for me. Is there any way how can I call hplShowMatrix as a part of C# procedure, let's say inside of protected void btnShowMatrix_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){} ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
protected void btnShowMatrix_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
   this.GetType(),"OpenWindow","window.open('http://localhost/IMApp/static/knit.html','_newtab');",true);
}
```

Comment: This gives me the following error message: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @SmithiM:- Do check that the url which you are using is correct!

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: @SmithiM:- Are you able to open the url `http://localhost/IMApp/static/knit.html` directly from your browser?

Comment: Yes, I can open that url from my browser.

Comment: @SmithiM:- This is strange as I tried the same code in my system and its working.(*I simply changed the url*)

Comment: Hmmm, that's really weird... Only if I create new Web Form, then into protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) insert string url = @"localhost/IMApp/static/knit.html";; Response.Redirect(url); and call this new web form from mainPage.aspx with Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
        this.GetType(), "OpenWindow", "window.open('http://localhost/IMApp/ShowMatrix.aspx','_newtab');", true);